# looking for a manga with a strong female lead saintess candidate who was engaged to the prince but was later replaced by a fake saintess

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm looking for a manga with a female lead that's able to defend herself. I don't think it's isekai, but her former fiance, the crown prince, annuls their engagement and later regrets his decision. Also, there's a white-haired priest character that tries to have her kidnapped. I think he might've led to her being replaced with a fake.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you remember any character or place names?

Comment: Just to be clear, this is a setting with magic? Usually, that's part of the Saintess setup, but I wanted to be sure.

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? And do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Comment: If I recall correctly the female lead had darkish reddish hair the crown prince had black hair, the fake saintess had reddish pink hair and the priest had white hair. There may be magic in the story, there was a prophecy about the saintess marrying the crown prince, which is why he dumps the female lead for the fake. I can’t remember any names unfortunately, I read it months ago.

Answer (score 0):

With your additional comment about hair colors, this may be less of a match, but [*When a Saint Who Lost Her Virginity Touches Love*](https://forum.novelupdates.com/threads/when-a-saint-who-lost-her-virginitiy-touches-love-%E7%B4%94%E6%BD%94%E3%82%92%E5%A4%B1%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E8%81%96%E5%A5%B3%E3%81%8C%E6%84%9B%E3%81%AB%E8%A7%A6%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89.158230/) has some matches:

[image: Title image of When a Saint Who Lost Her Virginity Touches Love]

> Leria, a girl around 12 years old awakened the power of a saint whom duty is to protect the country. When she got her power, from a poor viscount house, she turns up to a royal palace. To save people, she prays wholeheartedly everyday, and receives prince Evan, the second prince’s marriage proposal and spends her days happily. However, on a certain day the second holy maid’s power awaken and angel turns up in palace. Since it’s unusual that the power of two people awakes in the same generation, they promised to help each other. However one night, something happened. After praying, Leria got kidnapped by someone, and lost her purity. As a result, she doesn’t have the qualification of being a holy maiden anymore. The second prince’s broke off his engagement with her, and then she finds out that this was a plot between him and the other angel. She becomes the servant of those two people in love and is treated miserably until she meets someone…

The female protagonist does have reddish hair. However, the second prince, who she was engaged to, has whitish blonde hair. The first prince, who proposes to her after Her engagement to the second prince is broken, has dark hair. No priest, or prophecy, that I can find in the first few chapters. However, it does have a fake saintess, and a broken engagement to a prince.